# How to install python 2to3 on Amazon Linux EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I want to install **Python 2to3 tool** on Amazon Linux but I am unable to install it.
Please can someone help me with the steps.

I have tried the following but doesn't work.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-11 ~]$ sudo yum install python-tools
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                                  | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                               | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
1045 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package python-tools available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I have the following versions of python installed.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-11 bin]$ ls -rlt python*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5120 Nov  2 19:21 python2.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5120 Nov  2 19:21 python26
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1846 Jan 31 00:17 python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5120 Jan 31 00:18 python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5120 Jan 31 00:18 python27
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 6864 Feb  6 21:24 python3.4m
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 6864 Feb  6 21:24 python3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 6864 Feb  6 21:24 python34
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 6872 Feb 19 21:58 python3.6m
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 6872 Feb 19 21:58 python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 6872 Feb 19 21:58 python36 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Feb 27 05:28 python2 -> python2.6 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Apr 19 03:00 python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Apr 19 03:00 python-config -> /etc/alternatives/python-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Apr 19 03:00 python -> /etc/alternatives/python
```

I have also tried below link but not of any help
[Python Link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html#module-lib2to3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the name of a command, you can use `yum provides` to see if it's available in any packages in the repo:

```
yum provides \*bin/2to3
```

When I ran this on Amazon Linux, I found the following packages: `python27-tools` and `python36-tools`.

If it were not available in any packages, you could install this using `pip`:

```
sudo pip install 2to3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. `sudo yum python27-tools` worked for me.